# Y=1.QNan. C++ в чем может быть причина?

Tags: c++

Попытался сделать задачу из интернета на If,Else. В итоге X выводится нормально,а Y с QNan. Перепробовал много вариантов,или Qnan или 0.В чем может быть причина? Сейчас вроде бы вышел правильный ответ,можете посмотреть,код правильный?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<tgmath.h>
int main ()
{
double z=cos(1.3);
float x;
int y;
    if (z<0)
{
x=(z+z)+tan(z);
y=sin(x)+log(x)+log(x);
printf("X=%f\nY=%e,x,y);
}

else if (0<=z<8)
{

    x=log(pow(z,4))+z+z;
    y=sin(x)+log(x)+log(x);
printf("X=%f\nY=%e",x,y);
    }
else if(z>8)
{
x=cos(z)+(z+z);
y=sin(x)+log(x)+log(x);
printf("X=%f\nY=%e",x,y);
}

getchar();
}
```

Comment: Ответ получился X=-4.739563
Y=1.060998e-314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `y` объявлен как `int`, а выводить вы его пытаетесь спецификатором `%e`. Непорядок! Если вы его выведите как `%d`, никакого NaN не будет.

Ну, а если вы его делаете `double` - дело другое. Смотрите, `z` у вас 0.27 примерно, так что `x` у вас получается отрицательным, так? а `y` при вычислении берет от `x` логарифм. А что такое логарифм от отрицательного числа? вот вы и получаете NaN...

И, кстати,

```
if (0<=z<8)
```

правильно записывается как

```
if (0<=z && z<8)
```

В целом я бы записал ваш код так:

```
double y,z=cos(1.3), x = 2*z;
if (z<0)
{
    x+=tan(z);
}
else if (z<8)
{
    x+=4*log(z);
}
else
{
    x+=cos(z);
}
y=sin(x)+2*log(x);
printf("X=%lf\nY=%lf\n",x,y);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! С Вашего позволения,задам еще один вопрос,дабы не создавать еще одну тему. Делаю еще одну задачу сейчас,на циклы. Там нужно приравнять a=p,p остается неизвестной(т.е. просто как буквенное значение,не вычисляется в конце) компилятор ругает что константа не задана. Что нужно сделать,что бы это исправить?

Comment: Этот ответ - если устраивает - пометить как принятый, тем самым закрыв вопрос, и все-таки задать новый вопрос, приведя в нем код. Так будет лучше и с точки зрения правил RuSO, и для пользователей, буде они будут искать вопросы, связанные с их проблемами.